# Context of a JSONP return

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am familiar with JSON, jQuery, and AJAX but am now working on incorporating JSONP for a cross-domain script.

My question is the context of the function on return.  Suppose I have this approximate code:

```
$.ajax({
   data:"name=oliver&dob=1992-05-15",
   success:function(returndata){
      do_something(this, event){
         //calling element and/or event can be held this way when data returns
      }
   }
})
```

On JSON calls I can do the above, but so far for JSONP I'm left with adding:

```
window.triggerEvent=event;
window.triggerObject=this;
```

which the JSONP function can refer to.  BUT, which doesn't feel very safe or properly abstracted.  Is there any way to wrap the return JSONP function in a context or scope (hope that is the right term)?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want `this` to be?  What's `do_something`?  Why do you have `{}` after it?  Should that be `function(){}`?  Where are you trying to read `triggerEvent` and `triggerObject`?

Comment: I tested it (http://jsfiddle.net/qLL5gpk2/) and `this` seems to be the AJAX settings object.